# How can I generate markers by entering the coordinates of an api?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am developing a map that places a mark in the current position of the user and marks all the clinics of the api, I can not successfully map the clinics with their corresponding longitude and latitude, I get an error that I can not solve which is as follows: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: MarkerProps | Readonly): Marker', gave the following error.
The type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to the type 'number | (() => number)'.
The type 'undefined' is not assignable to the type 'number | (() => number)'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: MarkerProps, context: any): Marker', gave the following error.
The type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to the type 'number | (() => number)'. Any solution for my problem?

```
import React,  { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import contentUtils from '../../lib/contentUtils'
import Loader from '../spinner/Loader';
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, Marker } from  '@react-google-maps/api'



export const PruevaClinicLocator = () => {

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);

    const [currentLatitude, setCurrentLatitude] = useState(Number)
    const [currentLongitude, setCurrentLongitude] = useState(Number)

    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: 'google-map-script',
        googleMapsApiKey: "AIzaSyB17U-TaHiXF-egDyrrCT_kejxz5ckXDNA"
      })
    
      const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null)
     
    
      const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(center);
        console.log('iscenter',center)
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        setMap(map)
      }, [])
    
      const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        setMap(null)
      }, [])

    const containerStyle = {
        width: "100vw",
        height: "100vh"
      };

      const center = {
        lat: currentLatitude,
        lng: currentLongitude
      };

      const zoom = {
          zoom: 15
      }
  

      const fetchClinicList = async () => {
        getClinic().then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            setClinicList(response)
        }).catch ( (error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    useEffect (() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            console.log(position)
            setCurrentLatitude(position.coords.latitude)
            setCurrentLongitude(position.coords.longitude)
            fetchClinicList(); 

                    })
         }, []);
   
        

    return isLoaded ? ( 
        <div>
            <GoogleMap 
                zoom = { 10 } 
                mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
                center={center}
                onLoad={onLoad}
                onUnmount={onUnmount}
              
            >
        
                      <Marker position={{lat:currentLatitude, lng:currentLongitude}} />   
                      {clinicList.map(clinic => (
                          <Marker position={{lat:clinic.latitude , lng:clinic.parseInt(longitude)}} /> 
                      ))}     
            </GoogleMap> 
        </div>
    )  : <> </> 

}
```